# Canvas doesn't show shape

Tags: java, canvas

I started to learn about Canvas and I made a simple program. But It is not working. The shape is not shown on screen. I see just black screen. I am wondering what am I doing wrong?

Codes:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

class MyCanvas extends Canvas{
    public MyCanvas() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setSize(400,400);
    }

    public void print(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillOval(75, 75, 150, 75);
    }
}



public class Canvas1 extends JFrame {

    public Canvas1() {
        setTitle("Canvas1");
        setSize(400,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        add(new MyCanvas());
        setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Canvas1();

    }

}
```

Comment: Try calling `super.print(g)` in `print` before anything else.

Comment: Unresolved. I see black screen again.